# .htaccess rewrite but exclude password-protected directory results in 404 error

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, .htpasswd

I have a pretty URL setup with .htaccess that rewrites non-existent URLs (not strictly 404 errors) to a PHP script that serves either content or a 404 message. I have excluded existing files and directories from this rewriting so that CSS, images, etc, won't be affected.

However, there is one directory that is password-protected by .htpasswd that should also bypass the rewrite rule but is NOT when .htpasswd is enabled for it.

Parent directory .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /callbacks.php [L]
```

There's a child directory with the following .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

Options All -Indexes

AuthName "Backstage Access" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /path/to/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
require valid-user
```

If I remove the `require valid-user` line, the parent directory's rewrite rule ignores the child directory as I want, and I can access it from my browser. But when I turn on the authorization, the parent directory's .htaccess rewrites the child directory to `/callbacks.php`, resulting in the custom 404 error.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Obviously I cannot remove the need for password-protection. I tried removing the parent rewrite rule and instead simply using `/callbacks.php` as a 404 error document, but then POST and GET data isn't transferred.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it still actual, but I had the same problem and found a fix - add to your htaccess the following lines:

```
ErrorDocument 401 /somepage.html
ErrorDocument 403 /somepage.html
```

And this should be enough to bypass rewriter